# How to know if Drive is SSD or HDD through Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, ssd, hdd

I would like to know if there is a way through Terminal commands in Mac OS X to find out if an external drive is SSD or HDD.

Answer (score 9):

A very dirty solution ;-) : Enter `system_profiler | grep "Media Type: SSD"` in `Terminal.app`.

A more detailed approach is `system_profiler SPSerialATADataType` and you'll get all devices attached to your SATA interfaces with - beyond other informations - the `Medium Type` which may be Rotational or SSD.
By adding `-xml > ~/Desktop/MyReport.spx` you will get a XML-file on your desktop which can be opened by `System Information.app`.

Comment: For external drives..it dosent say much details...because all i got is Capacity,BSD Name,Content. any idea?

Comment: i'm looking into it...i fear it will be difficult

Comment: @WM. if you're using an USB drive, you could try `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`

Answer (score 9):

A super fast way to do this is to use `diskutil` to get this info:

```
diskutil info disk0 | grep "Solid State"
```

You will receive a "Yes/No" answer similar to the following:

```
Solid State:              Yes
```

Note:  This does not work for all USB drives (the USB to SATA interface must support the extended AT command set).